How to Share a Node with Multiple Parents in anytree?
I am trying to build a tree structure using Python's anytree library. However, I am facing an issue with sharing a node (specifically node 984) among multiple parents. Here is my code:
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
from anytree.exporter import UniqueDotExporter
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = np.array([
    [1000., 1001.,  998.,  988.,  980., 1003.],
    [1000.,  997., 1000.,  979., 1002., 1000.],
    [1000., 1003.,  996., 1006., 1003., 1002.],
    [1000.,  988.,  999.,  984.,  972.,  970.],
    [1000., 1000., 1032.,  984.,  982.,  976.],
    [1000., 1000., 1002.,  971.,  966.,  963.]
])

# Recursive function to build the tree structure
def add_to_tree(tree, path):
    node = tree
    for value in path:
        if value not in node:
            node[value] = {'count': 0, 'children': {}}
        node[value]['count'] += 1
        node = node[value]['children']

# Initialize the tree
tree = {}

# Build the tree
for row in data:
    add_to_tree(tree, row)

# Given tree structure dictionary
tree_structure = tree

# Function to create hierarchical tree nodes
def create_tree(tree_dict, parent=None):
    for key, value in tree_dict.items():
        node = Node(str(key), parent=parent)
        create_tree(value['children'], parent=node)

# Create the tree
root = Node("1000.0")
create_tree(tree_structure[1000.0]['children'], parent=root)

# Generate the tree diagram
output_path = "full_tree.png"
UniqueDotExporter(root).to_picture(output_path)

print(f"Tree diagram saved to {output_path}")

# Display the generated tree diagram in Colab
from IPython.display import Image
Image(output_path)



But I want this type

I tried Chatgpt, not working.

the definition of a tree is such that every node can only have one parent. The structure you are referring to is a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).
